# GatsbyJS + TypographyJS: How to make Typography take precedence?

Tags: css, fonts, gatsby, typography, bulma

I have a GatsbyJS app with TypographyJS (via Gatsby plugin) as well as Bulma CSS framework (via `import` in my `Layout` component) but Bulma's typography definitions always override my TypographyJS config.

How can I make it so that TypographyJS defs always come last and I still can utilize the grid layout and other elements of Bulma?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @HaseebBurki: 

Nope, sadly not - I've switched over to the [tachyons css framework](http://tachyons.io) which contains a good typography setup. Sorry for the late reply, hope it helps.